# How to add an additional custom row to a listview?

Tags: android, list, listview

As the title suggests I'm attempting to add an additional custom row to my list view to allow more customisation. I currently have one custom row set to the list view which as we know will continuously repeats depending on the amount of information input. Now that I'm want to expand the list view to display multiple custom rows I've become stuck in adjusting my code and would appreciate if someone could have a look.

I have provided a explanation of my current setup.

Firstly we have the view holder itself which works as an in between for setting the information.

```
public class ViewHolderWine {

public ImageView wineImage;
public TextView wineName;
public TextView  wineDes;
public TextView  winePrice;


public void setDataIntoViewHolder (List_String listString ){

    wineImage.setImageResource(listString.getIcon_wine());
    wineName.setText(listString.getWineName());
    wineDes.setText(listString.getWinedes());
    winePrice.setText(listString.getWinePrices());

}
```

Secondly we have my List_String in which the getters and setters have been made.

```
public class List_String {

int icon_wine;
String wineName;
String winedes;
String winePrices;


public List_String(int icon_wine, String wineName, String winedes, String winePrices) {
    this.icon_wine = icon_wine;
    this.wineName = wineName;
    this.winedes = winedes;
    this.winePrices = winePrices;

}

public String getWinePrices() {
    return winePrices;
}

public void setWinePrices(String winePrices) {
    this.winePrices = winePrices;
}

etc......
```

We next have the ListFragment

```
 public class List extends ListFragment {

java.util.List<List_String> lst;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  listData();
    // Adapter custom;


     Adapter myAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list, lst);

    setListAdapter(myAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}


public void listData() {

    lst = new ArrayList<List_String>();

    lst.add(new List_String(R.drawable.thumb, etc....
```

Finally I then brought all the pieces together using an adapter.

```
 public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<List_String> {

List<List_String> lstWine;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public Adapter(Context context, int resource, java.util.List<List_String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);


    lstWine = objects;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    ViewHolderWine viewholder;


    if (view == null){

        viewholder = new ViewHolderWine();


                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);

                viewholder.wineImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineImage);
                viewholder.wineName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineName);
                viewholder.wineDes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineDes);
                viewholder.winePrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.winePrice);



        view.setTag(viewholder);

    }else{

        viewholder = (ViewHolderWine) view.getTag();

    }

    List_String list = lstWine.get(position);
    viewholder.setDataIntoViewHolder(list);


    return view;

}
```

Comment: do you want to make an expandable list? or you just want some bottom rows to have a different look?

Comment: Basically some rows which have a different look to one above so that I can mix and match.

Comment: do they contain the same kind of data?

Comment: For example my first custom row uses 3 textviews and 1 image view. I was considering having one with Textview and switch. But once I figure out how to add one additional custom row then hopefully I can then take it from there.

Comment: Since you have different kind of data you need to create different adapters, which implies you will have a separate list view that you can place at the bottom of the other

Comment: Essentially you are saying to stack multiple list views in order to have a range of custom rows?

Comment: yes. Try that and let me know what you get

Comment: check this out http://neelansoft.com/stacktests/device-2017-02-17-195009.png

Comment: Hi that's exactly what I need, may I ask how you achieved this?

Comment: I used 2 list views with 2 separate adapters.

Comment: Could I possibly see how you set up your list views?

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout for the activity that hosts the list views is like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1">

     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ListView>
     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity class

```
//populate your first list
    myList.add(0, new Model("Full name 1", "Good"));
    myList.add(1, new Model("Full name 2", "Bad"));
    myList.add(2, new Model("Full name 3", "Worse"));
    myList.add(3, new Model("Full name 4", "Mediocre"));

//populate your second list
    myList2.add(0, new Model2("Full name 5", true));
    myList2.add(1, new Model2("Full name 6", true));
    myList2.add(2, new Model2("Full name 7", false));

//initialize adapters
    adapter = new mAdapter(StartActivity.this,myList);
    adapter2 = new mAdapter2(StartActivity.this,myList2);

//retrieve the list views
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

//set the adapters
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```